# Lwjgl Font Upside down

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

My rendered text appears upside down. I understand that the bottom left corner is position (0,0) and the entirety of my code is based around this. I have a feeling that the reason my text is rendered upside down is because I am using java's awt font class instead of `newdawn.slick.Font`. Is there a simple way to accomplish flipping is over? I tried using

```
glScalef(1, -1, 1);
```

to flip it however that cause everything to stop rendering.

Code below

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import java.awt.Font;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

public class FontRenderer {
    private TrueTypeFont font;

    public FontRenderer(){
        Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24);
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
    }

    public void render(float x, float y, String text){
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        font.drawString(x, y, text);
    }

    public void render(float x, float y, String text, float r, float g, float b)
    {
        Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        font.drawString(x, y, text, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory: why are you using the awt font class instead of the LWJGL font class?

Comment: would that be the newdawn.slick package? am i just using the wrong one because whenever I try to init the class it tells me I can not init.

Comment: so maybe its out of ignorance that im not...

Comment: Eh, nevermind, I see now that TrueTypeFont extends java.awt.Font. Although googling "lwjgl font upside down" does return a bunch of results, maybe that's a good place to start.

Comment: very curious as to why what was edited was edited out. I didnt see an explicit reason why. Is it not okay for me to thank the community for their time in advance?...

Comment: @KevinWorkman But there is not LWJGL font class. I have no idea what you are talking about, but OpenGL is just a graphics library. Nothing more.

Comment: @opiop65 I was just picking up on this sentence: "I have a feeling that the reason my text is rendered upside down is because I am using java's awt font class instead of newdawn.slick.Font", and I was curious about what happened when the OP explored that option. Then I realized that TrueTypeFont in fact extends java.awt.Font. Feel free to answer the question if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fonts are drawing upside down because Slick uses a origin in the top left corner, whereas by default LWJGL uses a origin in the bottom left. You stated that you know your origin is in the bottom left, so why would you expect your rendering code to work?